# Change IP adress with pupperteer doesn't seems to work. Am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, ip, puppeteer

I am currently trying to do web scraping with node and puppeteer headless chrome. I use a voting website, where you can vote only 1time/hour, and I am trying to vote more (like 10times/hour for exemple). For this purpose I use different IP adresses and different User Agent.
But, the problem is, when I switch IP it doesn't seems to work( I cannot put an other vote) and when I check my IP on (on some website like https://ipcost.com/) I see my real Ip address.

Here is the code I use to achieve this:

```
const chromeOptions = {
    headless:false,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: [
        '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process',
        '--flag-switches-begin --disable-site-isolation-trials --flag-switches-end',
        '--disable-features=UserAgentClientHint',
        `--proxy-server=http=user::passwordx@ip:port`
      ]
(async() => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch(chromeOptions);
....
})()
};
```

This is the first time I am working on web scraping and I use proxy like that.
I wasn't able to find any answer to my question, I think I am missing something or I am doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got the answer.
In fact pupperteer does not manage authentication proxy request
So I change

```
`--proxy-server=http=user::passwordx@ip:port`
```

by

```
`--proxy-server=http://ip:port`
```

and add

```
await page.authenticate({        
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password'
    })
```